# Preventing Crunchy Postgres Access from Terminal of OpenShift Pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, patroni, crunchy-postgresql-operator

I have a Crunchy Postgresql database running in an OpenShift pod.
The db is configured in the PostgresCluster.yaml file and then deployed through a pipeline.

The problem:
Everyone who have access to the terminal of the pod is able to access the data by simply typing `psql` in the terminal and then he is logged in as the superuser "postgres".

What I want to achieve:
Access to the db from the terminal should be authenticated.
For example: someone must enter the password of the user "postgres".

What I have tried:
Adding the following line to postgresCluster.yaml:

```
pg_hba:
  - local all postgres password 
  - local all postgres md5
  - host all all all
```

None of them worked.

I am thinking maybe I was working on the wrong file...

Comment: You might consider using Kubernetes RBAC to disallow `kubectl exec` for users who shouldn't have it.  This sort of concern isn't really the sort of programming-related issue that's usually on topic for Stack Overflow, though.